# Excel file used in C# application become visible when Microsoft Excel opened from outside the application and can't be closed

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm using Interop Excel and my code works fine

```
    class GeneralData
{   public static string excelPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\SteamProp";
    public static ExcelApp._Application oExcel;
    static ExcelApp.Workbooks oBooks;
    public static ExcelApp._Workbook oBook;
    static object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    // Function will be used in Main Form Load Method
    public static void OpenExcelConnection()
    {
        oExcel = new ExcelApp.Application();
        oExcel.Visible = false;
        oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
        oBook = oBooks.Open(excelPath, oMissing, oMissing,
            oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);            
    }


    public static void ReleaseExcel()
    {
        try
        {
            oBook.Close(true, excelPath, oMissing);
            oExcel.Quit();

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oBook);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oBooks);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oExcel);
            oBook = null;
            oBooks = null;
            oExcel = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```

I made (OExcel) static to use it from different forms.
I open the (OExcel) and use it then close at the end by calling the ReleaseExcel() Method.
The code work fine, but if there was any different excel file opened from outside the application, the file which used in the C# application appears to the user even that :

```
oExcel.Visible = false;
```

and when the ReleaseExcel() method called this file doesn't close, and if i closed the C# application and opened it again the next Exception is raised:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ". It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need Permission to view its data.

So Could you help me.

Answer (score 0):

When you done disposing the object, use

```
GC.Collect();
```

This is how I dispose my Excel object

```
        private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you still have your objects open (check your task manager); this should help you to close them and therefore ready to be re-opened again?